# Does Windows 8.1 ignore its primary language setting?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, input-languages

Since a few days, when I close and reopen Notepad++, it's input language is Dutch. I want this to be English unless I manually change it (which I rarely do). I do want to have Dutch available for these rare occasions.

I looked into my language settings and what I understand is that English is my "primary language". Is this setting erroneously ignored or do I need a different setting?

Note that things were working fine but then this problem suddenly appeared out of nowhere..

.[image]

Comment: There is a checkbox `Let me set a different input method for each app window` under `Advanced settings`. Uncheck it and save settings...

Comment: @JosefZ: that seems to resolve the issue. Perhaps you should post that as answer instead of comment? But anyway: thanks for your help, you made my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine further possible adjustment under `Advanced settings`; among others, next settings are important:

- *Override for Windows display language*: keep the default **Use language list (recommended)** option selected for this list;
- *Override for default input method*: change from default *Use language list (recommended)* to desired input method which *any* newly launched app window should **start with**; in your case it could be probably

  - **English (United States) - US** or
  - **English (United States) - United States - International**;
- *Switching input method*:

  - *Let me set a different input method for each app window* checkbox: **if unchecked**, changes previously adjusted *default input method* to recently selected one all windows-wide.

FYI, here are *my own* advanced language settings (with *Czech* instead of *Nederland*):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this method is still working on Win10 Version 1709 (up-to-date as-of 2018-01-22)!