# Set default input language on Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, language, input-languages

I have english version on Windows 10 Home installed on my computer. I want to use finnish input method with english language but it forces english as my input language. I have tried to add finnish as my input language but I can't set it as my main input. I have to manyally change the input language to finnish with win+space hotkey every time I start my computer. I can get finnish as default if I change my language but I want to keep using english as my display language. 
So, is there a way to force set finnish as main input language while still using english as your display language?

Comment: Check and set properly [Override for default input method](http://superuser.com/a/958430/376602). Then try [Apply language settings to the welcome screen...](http://superuser.com/a/948661/376602)